# Why can't I chown a VirtualBox shared folder?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, permissions, shared-folders

I'm trying to recursively `chown` a VirtualBox shared folder, but I can't get it to work:

```
$ ls -lah
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4.0K Aug  1  2012 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root   4.0K Jul 21  2012 ..
drwxrwx---  1 root vboxsf 4.0K May  4 17:02 sf_dev
drwxrwx---  1 root vboxsf 4.0K Sep  2 10:21 sf_dropbox
$ sudo chown -R pknight:pknight sf_dropbox && ls -lah
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4.0K Aug  1  2012 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root   4.0K Jul 21  2012 ..
drwxrwx---  1 root vboxsf 4.0K May  4 17:02 sf_dev
drwxrwx---  1 root vboxsf 4.0K Sep  2 10:21 sf_dropbox
```

I'm aware that I could just add a user to the vboxsf group (as it has full permissions), but I don't want to give every user/daemon full permissions to all of my shared folders.

I'm running VirtualBox 4.2.x, with Windows 7 as the host and both Xubuntu and Debian as guests.

Is there any way for me to change the owner/group of my VirtualBox shared directory?

Comment: Note that the accepted answer doesn't answer the question, and it's that question that I need an answer to.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The VirtualBox shared file system (vboxsf) doesn't support POSIX permissions *per se*; rather, they are "set" at mount time:

```
$ mount
...
dropbox on /media/sf_dropbox type vboxsf (gid=1001,rw)
```

The `gid` bit specifies the group that owns the directory; on my system, this happens to correspond with the vboxsf group.

You can alter the user and/or group ownership by remounting (must be done as `root`):

```
# mount -t vboxsf -o remount,gid=1000,uid=1000,rw dropbox /media/sf_dropbox
```

Replace `1000` with the desired user/group IDs, and `dropbox` with the name of the share (the part after `sf_`).

Note that this must be done after every reboot unless you edit `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: How to you edit fstab to do this?

Comment: @TheSmose see http://askubuntu.com/questions/252853/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder-at-startup for details about how to do this in Ubuntu (and probably other Debian-based distros as well). In the <options> field you'll most likely want to put `gid=1000,uid=1000,rw` (replace the user/group IDs as appropriate).

Answer (score 4):

These are the steps I followed, to get my *shared folder* to behave as expected:

## Shared Folder Setting

### Host

#### Add Shared Folder

[image: Add Shared Folder]

Reboot the guest.

#### Allow soft links

```
VBoxManage setextradata <guest vm> VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/<shared folder> 1
```

### Guest

#### Update guest additions

Devices -> Insert Guest Editions CD Image

#### add all necessary users to the vboxsf group

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf <username>
```

#### Change permissions

```
sudo chown -R <username>:<user group> /media/
```

Reboot the system.

#### Change ownership

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o gid=<username>,uid=<user group>,rw <share folder name> /media/sf_<share folder name>
```

#### This is the corresponding line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
data /media/sf_data vboxsf rw,nodev,relatime,iocharset=utf8,uid=982,gid=982 0 0
```

Note:
I'm still unable to change ownership to a random user on the *shared folder.*

Answer (score 1):

The vboxsf group has full access to the shared folder, so you should add your user to that group.

**Note:** you should set the option "Auto-mount" in VirtualBox shared folder settings.

Shared folder permissions:

```
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    0 feb  9 07:41 sf
```

Add your user to the vboxsf group:

```
usermod -aG vboxsf <youruser>
```

Reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```